# How to add code to compiled java class

Tags: disassembly, java, patching, function-hooking, compilers

I have java code that is compiled to a .class file.
There is a function that gets few parameters and do some action (e.g. get int x and int y and do x+y)

I want to add to this .class file code that checks if x=1 and call to another function(e.g. call to x-y and don't do x+y)

How can edit a compiled .class file and add my own code?

Comment: I edited the question, hopefully this is what you actually wanted to ask; if not, please clarify in a comment or edit it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to achieve this:

1. Decompile .class to .java source (not necessarily original source, but equivalent), make your changes, compile again. There are many Java decompilers out there, I won't list them all.
2. Disassemble .class to "assembly" (usually Jasmin syntax), modify it, assemble back. [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) is a good tool that should be able to do it.
3. Use a tool that can modify/patch the bytecode directly in the .class file. I haven't tried it, but [Recaf](https://github.com/Col-E/Recaf) claims to be able to do it.
4. Hook the Java runtime interpreter to catch the moment it starts executing the target function and  make it execute something else instead. This is somewhat implementation-specific but here's one example I know about which uses Java debugging protocol (JWDP): https://github.com/CrowdStrike/pyspresso

Answer (score 2):

You can use JByteMod to edit your class bytecode.
You can also create new methods, delete methods, fields and change accesses.

Its pretty easy to use, just load the jar and select the class you want to edit.

JByteMod: https://github.com/GraxCode/JByteMod-Beta/releases

Comment: JByteMod hasn't had an update in two years now unfortunately. The author has jumped on different projects though in similar natures.